# Group node from OG membership doesn't work

Tags: views, organic-groups

I want to create some views to display Group information on Group content pages. E.g. Display contact info from the group in a block/pane in the sidebar.

I did this before, by using the default OG Content view and add the relations.

1. I add the relationship OG membership: Group Node from OG membership, and sets its relation to (OG membership from node)
2. Set the contextual filter to provide a default value (Current OG group from context) and keep relation set to the default OG membership from Node.
3. Add fields and set their relation to Group node from OG Membership.

This isn't working though, it gives no results when viewing on Groupcontent-pages. It gives only results when viewing the Grouppage itself. I do not know why this is not working the way it should. As I recall I never had this problem before.

I used Organic Groups 7.x-2.7 with Panopoly 7.x-1.30. I have this on 2 separate installs (one on Acquia site, and one in my VM). The VM has only Panopoly and OG (and dependencys) installed as extra so it's almost vanilla.

I have enabled OG Context of course.

How can I solve this? Without these views it's a pain for the user to see in which groupcontext they are browsing.

EDIT:
I installed a vanilla drupal (Not Panopoly). Installed OG + dependencys.
Then I created an empty view and added the following:
1. Relationship: OG membership: OG membership from Node group (required)
2. Contextual: (OG membership from node group) OG membership: Og membership ID
and Current OG group from context

This works! However, this doesn't work in Panopoly... Is this the new way to work with OG and Groupinfo on groupcontent pages?

The SQL-querys views does are exactly the same. Though on Panopoly there are no results. On Vanilla Drupal there is.
How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The panel needed the relationship. This can be added on the contexts-page of the panel. The relation I added was:
 Node from Node (on Node: Groups audience [og_group_ref])

When this is added it can be chosen instead of "This node" when Views panes are added to a page-layout.

This works with the default OG Content-view with the relation OG membership: Group Node from OG membership added to it. (on groups without content this gives No content in this group however.)